# Redirect loop when forwarding to mobile site

Tags: plugins, subdomains, wp-redirect, add-submenu-page, dns

I have successfully redirected my page to *m.example.com* from *example.com* when i open in mobile environment with this code in *functions.php*

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirecting_to_mobile_site');
function redirecting_to_mobile_site(){
$requri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

 if( wp_is_mobile() )
 {
  $redcont = "http://m.example.com".$requri;
  wp_redirect( $redcont, 301 ); exit;
 }
}
```

I also created a sub-domain through WP sub-domain plugin.

But when I click any link from index page it says "**This page has redirect loop**"

Please advise how to enable sub-domain for internal pages.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that you aren't already on the mobile site:

```
function redirecting_to_mobile_site() {
    if ( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] !== 'm.example.com' && wp_is_mobile() ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://m.example.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirecting_to_mobile_site' );
```

You'll need to clear your browser cache to properly test the fix.

Comment: i have used this code and desktop and mobile both version fail to load... please please provide other solutions

Comment: is this correct in your code?  if ( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] !== 'm.collegeswaggy.com' && wp_is_mobile() ) {

Comment: Use `var_dump( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ); exit;` and let me know what the result is.

Comment: this comes on mobile and desktop browser string(17) "example.com"

Comment: Hmm, we'll need another way to detect if we're currently on the mobile site. Try `print_r( $_SERVER ); exit;`

Comment: Array ( [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache [REQUEST_URI] => / [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home4/bword/public_html [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1 [HTTP_HOST] => example.com  [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36 [HTTP_X_HTTP_PROTO] => HTTP/1.1  [QUERY_STRING] => [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200 [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home4/bword/public_html/index.php [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php  [SERVER_NAME] => example.com [SERVER_PORT] => 80 [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1

Comment: is this correct in your given code  [$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] !== 'm.example.com'], !== ?

Comment: Do you get that same response when you visit `m.collegeswaggy.com`?